# The select2('val') method was called on an element that is not using Select2

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I'm having problem with implementing Select2 into my application. The documentation is pretty straight forward but for some reason I cannot even do the simplest example with multiple selection.

I have created a plunker with an example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/v4vPlMgyL7oJe2EjFc6r?p=preview)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select style="width: 400px;" ui-select2="select2Options" multiple ng-model="selectedTags">
    <option ng-repeat="tag in tags" value="{{tag.id}}">{{tag.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>


myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.tags = [
    {id: 0, name: "Zero"},
    {id: 1, name: "One"},
    {id: 2, name: "Two"}, 
    {id: 3, name: "Three"}, 
    {id: 4, name: "Four"}, 
];

$scope.select2Options = {
        allowClear: true,
        multiple: true
    };

})
```